# MPICC: where to find OpenMPI's mpicc's "showme" when using MVAPICH2's mpicc

Tags: mpi, openmpi, mvapich2

I want to find mvapich2's equivalent of OpenMPI's `--showme` flags. In particular, I'm trying to compile a library that I did not develop with the following code in its local.mk file:

```
# If using OpenMPI, and mpicc is in your path, then no modification here is 
# necessary.  Otherwise, fill in appropriate flags here
MPI_COMPILE_FLAGS = -DOMPI_SKIP_MPICXX=1 $(shell mpicc --showme:compile)
MPI_LINK_FLAGS = $(shell mpicc --showme:link)
```

`MPI_COMPILE_FLAGS` and `MPI_LINK_FLAGS` are passed on to parts of the Makefile proper which compile the requisite scripts.

However, I am not using OpenMPI: I am using mvapich2 (version 2.3.6). I need to use mvapich2 because it corresponds better with the cluster I'm using. But I cannot find the equivalent of `--showme:compile` or `--showme:link` in the `--help` call for `mpicc`, or in any of the documentation for `mvapich2`. I've tried every variation of the `--help` call (including sending the output of `-v` to a text file so that I could search `compile`, `flag`, `output`, and `print` by regexp), to no avail.

More frustratingly, I can't even get an example of OpenMPI running so that I can see what `--showme:compile` or `--showme:link` is supposed to do. I know the OpenMPI documentation says they're supposed to "Output the compiler/linker flags that would have been supplied to the C compiler", but I don't even know what form that output takes so that I can assess the suspects for mvapich2 that I thought might work: my best (not good) guess so far was that the `-Wl,` family of commands are possibly what I want, but the comma delimitation doesn't seem right and it's trying to find a set of option that I'm supplying, which seems unsuitable for what I want. I just know that the things that I've tried haven't worked.

How can I get a `--showme` equivalent to work here?

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
mpicc -show
```

On my system that gives:

```
icc -lmpi -lmlx5 -I/opt/apps/intel19/mvapich2-x/2.3/include -L/opt/apps/intel19/mvapich2-x/2.3/lib64 -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/opt/apps/intel19/mvapich2-x/2.3/lib64 -Wl,--enable-new-dtags
```